# clj repl crashing when launched and pwd is ~

Tags: clojure

clj repl crashing when launched and pwd is ~, otherwise from any other directory it's fine.

I installed clojure following instructions from
https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started#_installation_on_linux

However, when i launch the repl staying in ~, I get following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.main/main

    at clojure.lang.Var$Unbound.throwArity(Var.java:45)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:28)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:40)
```

And if i change the directory to any other location, it runs ok

```
:~/src$ clj
Clojure 1.10.3
user=>
```

My OS is a Debian Buster (Minimal)... I tried looking up, but to no avail...I also have no clue as to what to look for...

Not sure if following is of any help...

```
:~$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Debian, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.19.0-17-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

```
:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Just to have ti asked: is there a `deps.edn` file in your ~?

Comment: It's not there in my ~, but there is one inside ~/.clojure/deps.edn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the behavior is explained in one of the [comments](https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/10784/repl-crashing-when-launched-otherwise-from-other-directory?show=10814#c10814) by [Sean Corfield](https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/user/Sean+Corfield) on Clojure Q&A.